# angular-meteor: $stateParams undefined

Tags: angular-meteor

As in the title, `$stateParams` will return undefined.
The route where I define the param works fine, and the url gets the parameter that is being passed.
The module in that view I'm redirected to works but I get the said error.
The module looks like this:

```
class TripDetailsModuleCtrl {
   constructor($scope, $stateParams) { 
      'ngInject'; 
      $scope.viewModel(this); 
      console.log($stateParams); // returns undefined
   }
}
```

How else should I try to access `$stateParams`?

Comment: I noticed that the first argument will always return the `$scope`, and second is always `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having this issue, if your component is defined like this:
`controller: ['$scope', TripDetailsModuleCtrl]`
make sure to pass `$stateParams` as an argument there like so:
`controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams', TripDetailsModuleCtrl]`